# working with the desired day in the dataset

Tags: r

He says that the object "europe" could not be found. this is what I want to learn. To find the death numbers of the European countries only in the dataset. to show the country name and number of deaths in two columns.

`df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')`

`df1 <- aggregate(death~countryName, subset(df, region =="Europe"), sum)`

I will ask. but I want to learn something. In the data set, the number of deaths is given for each day. the code you have created has collected every day. my wish is only deaths. The prefix is ​​enough to give the number of deaths of the day. He added the numbers of deaths everyday to date and added them. high figures.

not max. because he doesn't want the highest death. he wants to know how many died yesterday.

Comment: Can you better clarify your question? In its current form, this question may be closed b/c it's unclear what your goal is.

Comment: I want to view the European countries and deaths. the dataset is set by date. I want the number of deaths compared to the previous day. how can i find yesterday's death number.

Comment: The code you posted works for me, or am I missing something?

Comment: the code is working. but it gives the total number of deaths. I need only how many people died yesterday. of course you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, and to manipulate most data, if with the use of the `dplyr` R package.  As is the case with most R packages, `dplyr` can be installed by running `install.pacakage("dplyr")`.  Make sure to call the `dplyr` library before using it by running `library(dplyr)` or by placing `dplyr::` in front of any functions from the `dplyr` package you use.  My code chunks below will illustrate both methods.

Below returns two columns, `countryName` and a calculated column `totalDeaths`, for European countries only.  `totalDeaths` is defined as the total deaths in the data for the given country.

```
## load the data
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
## copy the data to a new data frame to preserve original
df1 <- df
## filter data to only entries from the Europe region
df1 <- filter (df1, region == "Europe")
## group data by country
df1 <- dplyr::group_by(df1, countryName)
## calculate total deaths by grouping (in this case by country)
df1 <- dplyr::summarise(df1, totalDeaths = sum(deaths))
## ungroup to avoid errors
df1 <- dplyr::ungroup(df1)
```

Below will calculate deaths yesterday in each country in the data set:

```
## call the dplyr library
library(dplyr)
## read the source data
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
## copy df to df1 for preservation of original data
df1 <- df
## group the data by country for manipulation
df1 <- group_by(df1, countryName)
## create a variable yesterdayDeaths that adds the death column if the corresponding day  entry equals yesterday which will account for the possibility of duplicate country/day combinations
df1 <- summarise(df1, yesterdayDeaths = sum(ifelse(day == Sys.Date()-1, death, 0)))
## ungroup the data to avoid data manipulation errors
df1 <- ungroup(df1)
```

Or if you'd like to cut straight to the chase you can use the `dplyr` R package to create "pipes".  This is done using `%>%` at the end of each function in a sequence or "pipe".  Pipes push data from the previous function  in the sequence to the next and allow for omitting the `data` input of each function after the first.

Below is how you'd use "pipes" from the `dplyr` package:

```
## if using this method make sure dplyr package is installed
## call dplyr library in order to pipe data
library(dplyr)
## create our data frame
df <- 
  ## read the source data
  read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv') %>% 
  ## group data by country
  group_by(countryName) %>% 
  ## create a variable yesterdayDeaths that adds the death column if the corresponding day  entry equals yesterday which will account for the possibility of duplicate country/day combinations 
  summarise(yesterdayDeaths = sum(ifelse(day == Sys.Date()-1, death, 0))) %>%
  ## ungroup the data
  ungroup()
```

If you wanted to instead calculate deaths yesterday in each region you would change `countryName` to `region` within the `group_by()` function in either set of code given above.

I hope this helps!